# Help with proof to show $f \in C(X,Y)$ implies [$U \subset Y \text{ is open } \Rightarrow f^{-1}(U) \text{ is open }$]

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have been reading the book "Modern Real Analysis" by Ziemer. I have come to an exercise in the chapter on topology that I am having some trouble with. The exercise goes :

> If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, prove that $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open whenever $U \subset Y$ is open.

Note that I am using the convention that $\subset$ and $\subseteq$
are equivalent (as is done in the book).

This exercise appears in the section on metric spaces, so I assume that the topologies on $X$ and $Y$ are those induced by a pair of metrics (say $\rho$ and $\sigma$) defined on these sets.

I am able to show the backward implication, and it also seems that I'm able to show the forward implication if constraints are placed on the open set $U \subset Y$. The constraint is $U \subset f(X)$. I do not yet have a way for account for the case where $U \not \subset f(X)$. I would like help finding a way to account for this case.

Here is my proof so far for the forward implication from the exercise :

Let the metric spaces be $(X,\rho)$ and $(Y,\sigma)$. Let the induced topologies be
$(X,\mathcal{T})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{S})$.

Prove :
\begin{equation} 
f \in C(X,Y) \Rightarrow \left[ U \in \mathcal{S} \Rightarrow f^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{T} \right] 
\end{equation}
Let $U \in \mathcal{S}$ and $x_{0} \in f^{-1}(U)$. Define :
\begin{align}
\mathcal{B}_{X} & = \{ B(x,r) \in \mathcal{T} \; \mid \; x \in X \text{ and } r > 0 \}\\
\mathcal{B}_{Y} & = \{ B(y,r) \in \mathcal{S} \; \mid \; y \in Y \text{ and } r > 0 \}
\end{align}
We know :
\begin{equation}
U \in \mathcal{S} \Rightarrow \exists B\left( f(x_{0}) , r \right) \subset U \text{ for some } r > 0
\end{equation}
since $\mathcal{B}_{Y}$ is a basis for $(Y,\mathcal{S})$.

Now let $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ be s.t. $\epsilon \in ( 0 , r ]$. We know :
\begin{align}
f \in C(X,Y) 
 & \Rightarrow \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. } \sigma\left( f(x_{0}) , f(x) \right) < \epsilon \text{ when } \rho(x_{0},x) < \delta\\
 & \Rightarrow \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. } f(x) \in B\left( f(x_{0}), \epsilon \right) \text{ when } x \in B(x_{0},\delta)
\end{align}
We see :
\begin{align}
x \in B(x_{0},\delta) 
 & \Rightarrow f(x) \in B\left( f(x_{0}), \epsilon \right) \subset U \\
 & \Rightarrow f(x) \in U \\
 & \Rightarrow x \in f^{-1}(U) \\
 & \Rightarrow B(x_{0},\delta) \subset f^{-1}(U)
\end{align}
Define :
\begin{equation}
W = \{ U \in \mathcal{S} \; \mid \; U \subset f(X) \}
\end{equation}
We see that :
\begin{equation}
U \in W \text{ and } f(x) \in U \Rightarrow \exists B(x,\delta) \in \mathcal{B}_{1} \text{ s.t. } B(x,\delta) \subset f^{-1}(U)
\end{equation}
Let :
\begin{equation}
L(U) = \{ B(x,\delta) \in \mathcal{B}_{1} \; \mid \; f(x) \in U \text{ and } B(x,\delta) \subset f^{-1}(U) \}
\end{equation}
We can see :
\begin{equation}
f^{-1}(U) = \bigcup L(U)
\end{equation}
and :
\begin{equation}
[ D \in L(U) \Rightarrow D \in \mathcal{T} ] \Rightarrow f^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{T} \; \checkmark
\end{equation}
So when $U \in W$ we know it works. But what about for $U \not \in W$ ? This is what I would like help with.

Comment: If U is not in W f^-1(U) = f^-1(U intersection f(X)) and U intersection f(X) is in W so therefore f^-1(U intersection f(X)) is open, hence f^-1(U) is open

Comment: (1) What is your definition of "continuous"? I ask because what you give is usually **the** definition of continuous function. (2) The problem is about topological spaces; yet you start by assuming you have *metric* spaces. Are you supposed to do that? Has the book only defined topologies for metric spaces?

Comment: Arturo.  This exercise appears in a section on metric spaces that is within the chapter on topology.  In an earlier section they gave the general definition of a continuous function defined between topological spaces, so here I'm assuming they mean the definition of continuity that appears for metric spaces in the section the exercise appears in.

Comment: latbbites. How do we know that $U \cap f(X)$ is open ?  It would have to be open to be a member of $W$.

Comment: It doesn’t matter if $U \subset f[X]$ or not. They can even be disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

There are all manner of superfluous definitions, it's really much simpler:

Let $f$ be metric-continuous and $U$ open in $Y$.
We want to see that $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X$. So let $x_0 \in f^{-1}[U]$ be arbitrary. We know $f(x_0) \in U$ which is open so there is some $r>0$ so that $B(f(x_0), r) \subseteq U$. Applying the metric continuity at $x_0$ for $\varepsilon = r$ we get some $\delta>0$ so that

$$\forall x' \in X: \rho(x_0, x') < \delta \implies \sigma(f(x_0), f(x')) < r\tag{1}$$

It follows that $B(x_0, \delta) \subseteq f^{-1}[U]$ right away: if $x' \in B(x_0, \delta)$ then $\rho(x_0,x') < \delta$ so $(1)$ tells us that $f(x') \in B(f(x_0),r) \subseteq U$; in particular: $f(x') \in U$ so that $x' \in f^{-1}[U]$. That shows the inclusion and as $x_0 \in f^{-1}[U]$ was arbitrary, $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in the topology induced by $\sigma$. QED.

The reverse implication (when inverse images of open sets are open, then $f$ is metric continuous) is most easily seen by noting that all metric balls in $Y$ are open in $Y$, so for any $x_0\in X$ and any $\epsilon>0$, $x_0 \in f^{-1}[B(f(x_0), \epsilon)]$ and as the latter set is open by assumption our $\delta>0$ follows from $x_0$ being interior etc.